# Failed PR in conda-forge, but successful on local computer (conda build .)

Tags: python, c++, conda, conda-forge

I'm Fu, recently I have developed a python/c++ package, and I want to publish it to `conda-forge`. I have successfully built it in macOS and Windows by PR to `conda-forge`, and successfully used `conda build .` in macOS and Linux(red hat). But always failed in the Linux platform as PR to `conda-forge`.

The error occurred in the test stage, said can't import the package, although I have successfully installed it, so weird. Is there some trick? Does anybody want to have a look at my recipes and project, or who should I ask for help?

The staged-recipes is in https://github.com/shakeflow/staged-recipes, and the project is in https://github.com/shakeflow/noiseflow, the PR is in https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes/pull/23313

Best,
Fu

I have tried in local macos and linux(red hat), and macos windows in azure pipeline as a PR to conda-forge, they are all successful. Only failed in linux as a PR to conda-forge.

Comment: Questions should contain all necessary details without relying on external links. Please show a [mre] and include the full error message